# Add new Minio server to an already running pool

Tags: storage

I have [Minio](https://minio.io/) deployed using docker swarm on a single host, using 2 services and 8 volumes/folders (each service uses 4 volumes/folders).

The data folder inside Minio containers uses a `bind` mount type:

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt o=bind \
    --opt device=/host/pathN/ minioN-data # Where minioN-data goes from 1 to 8
```

Now I need to add a second host to improve availability, the new host will have its own volumes created on the same manner.

What is the best approach to add a new host without having to bring the running server down?

Should I `docker swarm join` from the new host into the running host? How will swarm/minio be able to handle files being stored in a different host from the container (i.e. service will start on host 2 but data files are on host 1)

Should I make it a new docker swarm instance and make them talk to each other via http? i.e. `minio serve http://host1/data1 http://host1/data2 http://host2/data1 http://host2/data2`. If that is the case, will Minio be able to copy everything from host1 to host2?

Will any of these solutions allow me to bring host1 or host2 down at will for maintenance and then bring it back up again without losing data?

Comment: [meta] sorry for the lack of proper tags, I can't create new tags nor ask for the creation over meta.serverfault

Answer (score 0):

You can't add new volumes or hosts into a running Minio setup, they are static.

What ended up working for me was to make sure that the volumes were available via NFS to all docker nodes and starting new servers on top of that NFS mount